# How to quickly check strings for correct English words? - Python

Tags: python, performance, nltk

I have a column in a pandas dataframe where each cell contains a rather long string of words. These strings are from an SQL database and contain a mix of words and alphanumeric id phrases which are not English, separated by spaces. These strings can be up to the character max of SQL. This is also not a small dataframe, i have several million rows.

The question is, what is the fastest way to keep only correct English words for each cell?

Below is my initial method which seemingly would take days to complete based on the speed suggested from tqdm (hence the progress_apply).

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import words
from tqdm import tqdm

def check_for_word(sentence):
    s = sentence.split(' ')
    for word in s:
        if word not in words.words():
            s.remove(word)
    return ' '.join(s)

tqdm.pandas(desc="Checking for Words in keywords")
df['keywords'] = df['keywords'].progress_apply(check_for_word)
```

Is there a method which would be significantly faster?

Thanks for your help!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The answer below was very helpful and took less than a second to run (GREAT IMPROVEMENT!). In the end I had to change from nltk.corpus words to nltk.corpus wordnet, as words was not exhaustive enough of a list for my purposes. The final result ended up being:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from tqdm import tqdm

def check_for_word(s):
    return ' '.join(w for w in str(s).split(' ') if len(wordnet.synsets(w)) > 0)

tqdm.pandas(desc="Checking for Words in Keywords")
df['keywords'] = df['keywords'].progress_apply(check_for_word)
```

which took 43 seconds to run.

Comment: What is `words`? A list of all English words? Is it sorted?

Comment: Woops. Sorry that is part of nltk corpus. ill update the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`words.words()` returns a list, which takes `O(n)` time for checking whether a word is present in the list or not. To optimize the time complexity, you can take create the set out of this list which offers the constant time search.
Second optimization is that `remove()` method on list takes `O(n)` time. You can maintain a separate list to remove that overhead. To know more about the complexity of various operations, you can refer to https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt

```
set_of_words = set(words.words())

def check_for_word(sentence):
    s = sentence.split(' ')
    return ' '.join(w for word in s if word in set_of_words)
```

Comment: set offers nominally O(1) search, not logarithmic.

Comment: You should be constructing `filtered_words` in  a generator  comprehension. It'll be much faster: `return ' '.join(w for w in s.split() if w in set_of_words)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for the feedback. I made those changes.